# como llamar archivos de otros directorios en php,

Tags: php

ya lo intente con el requiere_once y el included pero me sigue saliendo un error:

[image: este es el resultado que me da]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código mejor ponerlo en formato texto incrustado a la pregunta y no una imágen

Answer (score 2):

La página menú que te da el error esta en *vistas/aplication* y estas intentando acceder a dos directorios más arriba pero solo usas un *escape de directorio*.

Con la instrucción que estas usando estarías buscando `claseheredada.php` dentro de la *carpeta vistas* y no es ahí donde parece estar.

**Ejemplo actualizado:**

```
require_once '../../modelo/claseheredada.php';
```